# Changing Gas Price value in Metamask input field with JS

Tags: transactions, metamask, gas, gas-price, gas-estimate

Hello I have a problem when I need to accelerate transaction in Metamask, I want to increase the gas fee price but it`s not working...

As u can see in image I run script to change value but metamask back to previous value, its also have spin inside this input value.

How to make this work please help?

The code that I`m using to change the value is:

`document.querySelector("#popover-content > div > div > section > div > div > div.edit-gas-display > div.edit-gas-display__content > div.advanced-gas-controls > div:nth-child(3) > label > div.numeric-input.numeric-input--error > input[type=number]").value = 65`

I`m new in JS so have another way to make it change this value?

Contact me please i need help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this is when you interact with smart contract method in js their specified gasprice and gaslimit with method.

You try this:

```
const transactionParameters = {
  nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  gas: '0x2710', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', // Required except during contract publications.
  from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
  value: '0x00', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account.
  data:
    '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057', // Optional, but used for defining smart contract creation and interaction.
  chainId: '0x3', // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
};

// txHash is a hex string
// As with any RPC call, it may throw an error
const txHash = await ethereum.request({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [transactionParameters],
});
```

You can read more about it form [Metamask Docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html#example)